# example helm chart for getting iis metrics from a win2022 pod into datadog

Tags: iis, datadog

imagine the following situation:
AKS win2022 k8s Node with a datadog agent container running on it using helm.datadoghq.com.
On this node we have one or more aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 Pods which are running IIS.

I want the existing datadog agent to take the IIS metrics from the Pod(s) and report them in datadog portal, without having to run an extra datadog agent in the Pods.

Looking for an example values.yaml for this.

Thank you and best regards,
Floris

Datadog support doesn't have such example.